# How to write to Firebase table only if its greater than current value in table

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update the table level value in Firebase score table only if the table value is less than the value currently being posted to update. So the `KeyOfLevel` value never decreases.

Since the client side involved too much calls to fetch and check. I need to do this in rules tab of Firebase. And I don't exactly know how to write those rules.

Eg:

```
score: 
{
    "1234567890": 
    {
        CoinsKey: 1000,
        KeyOfLevel: 5
    }
}
```

where 123456789 is the user ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to write security rules like this.

```
{
   "rules": {
      "score": {
        "$userId": {
           "KeyOfLevel": {
              ".validate": "!data.exists() || data.val() < newData.val()"
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In place of `.validate` you can also use `.write`

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for the answer :). This works but it doesn't push the first score values in case of a new user or if the values don't exist. How should i skip that

Comment: @Koncorde You need to check for data existence. I've updated the answer. Please check if it helps!

Comment: Super Ravi. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes it helps. Works for me.

Comment: This is a really good solution! I'll add that `.validate` do not cascade like `.write` and `.read`: you'll need them somewhere on your node as well